# Bug UITapGestureRecognizer on UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

Adding UITapGestureRecognizer on UIScrollView. Tap is not recognised sometimes. The problem is occuring occasionaly and only on iPhone 6s +.

I could not find the cause.

I created a simple source for testing.

https://github.com/aurasw/UIScrollView-Bug/tree/master

Comment: Are you running this in simulator or in device?

Answer (score 0):

UIScrollView itself has gestures, and it tries to delay content touches to wait for someone to scroll.

In the attributes inspector, uncheck the delays content touches if you want the tap to have maximum priority.

[image]

Comment: The cause of the problem as I think your right.
I tried uncheck the delays content touches.
But problem still occurs.
It is sometimes occurs 
Just on iPhone 6s+